# Why Android BluetoothDevice.conenctGatt require context if it not use it

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing android app for ble communication.

My question is why the function

```
public BluetoothGatt connectGatt(Context context, boolean autoConnect,BluetoothGattCallback callback, int transport)
```

requires `Context` as parameter, I dug down the functions and found that it not using it anywhere as you can see here:

```
public BluetoothGatt connectGatt(Context context, boolean autoConnect,
                                     BluetoothGattCallback callback, int transport,
                                     boolean opportunistic, int phy, Handler handler) {
        if (callback == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("callback is null");

        // TODO(Bluetooth) check whether platform support BLE
        //     Do the check here or in GattServer?
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        IBluetoothManager managerService = adapter.getBluetoothManager();
        try {
            IBluetoothGatt iGatt = managerService.getBluetoothGatt();
            if (iGatt == null) {
                // BLE is not supported
                return null;
            }
            BluetoothGatt gatt = new BluetoothGatt(iGatt, this, transport, opportunistic, phy);
            gatt.connect(autoConnect, callback, handler);
            return gatt;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}
        return null;
    }
```

The weird thing is that this property not marked as deprecated too.
I tried to pass null instead of the context and seems that it works fine () with context or without.

Anyone know why is it there?

Comment: Did you check the history of the file?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I was reviewing and restructuring some old code and came across the same thing.  The main activity was being passed down into this method which seemed very odd to me.  I couldn't think of any reason why it would need to get a handle on the activity.  I'm changing it to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, based on short browsing of the Android source code repository this seems to be a remnant of an older design. The `connectGatt` function creates a `BluetoothGatt` object whose constructor preivously needed a `Context` argument. (This was [way back in API 18](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-4.3_r1/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#1194).) `BluetoothGatt` originally needed the `Context` object for [something](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9908112fd085d8b0d91e0562d32eebd1884f09a5/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#124) but the code had been removed before the class even [became public](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-4.3_r1/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java) six years ago. The `Context` argument in the constructor, however, remained. About three years ago it was [finally removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/adc26ec1b4060358d918d1bdf491f5192b35c2d3), but by then the `connectGatt` API has been public for years and they couldn't remove the now useless argument without breaking a lot of existing code. So they didn't.

Think of it as the human appendix or the tailbone - a vestigial remnant left behind by evolution :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that's 100% safe. They might decide in a future Android version to use the context again for something. I mean, they probably won't but you never know. Anyway, it's certainly not needed _now_.

Comment: Yes i understand the risk, anyway i build the system in way that the place where i call the connectGatt()  function is far away from context.